# how to specify a range in switch case in java

Tags: java, switch-statement, range

Just started writing code in java and is learning normal logic operations. While using a switch case I wanted to specify a range and am not able to do it.
switch (input){
case 0-20 :
System.out.println("Your grade is F");
break;

```
            case 21-40 :
                System.out.println("Your grade is D");
                break;

            case 41-60 :
                System.out.println("Your grade is C");
                break;

            case 61-80 :
                System.out.println("Your grade is B");
                break;

            case 81-100 :
                System.out.println("Your grade is A");
                break;
```

Can anybody help me

Comment: No way, you need a chain of `if`-statements for that.

Comment: I wouldn't use a `switch/case` for this.  I'd use a `TreeMap` that stores the smallest number of each range as the key, and the grade as the value.  You can then use `floorEntry` on a score to convert it to a grade.

Comment: Actually, ignore my last comment.  I notice that you've said you just started learning Java.  In that case, use a chain of `if` and `else`, as suggested by Alexander.

Comment: Off topic: Generous grade ranges. In my past, it was typically 91-100 A, 81-90 B, ... At some schools, that was generous.

Comment: As previous comments have said, you should use `if ... else if ...` chain. But, if you insist on using `switch`, you can use a little math to take advantage of the fact that the range always spans 20 points: `int k = (input - 1) / 20; switch (k) { case 0: ... case 4: ...`.

Comment: As suggested, use `if/else` statements.  But if you put them in the correct order you only need to do a single test for each range.  Example, first test for `> 80`, then test for `> 60`, etc.  The last range need not be tested as none are left, so the grade is assigned directly in a single else clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java `switch { case:` wasn't designed to use ranges.

You can use a chain of `if ... else if` like this:

```
if (input >= 81) System.out.println ("Congratulations! Your grade is A");
else if (input >= 61) System.out.println ("Your grade is B");
else if (input >= 41) System.out.println ("Your grade is C);
```

Note this uses the suggestion from the comment from WJS. If you code several lines like this

```
else if (input >= 61 && input <= 80) ...
```

, there is a greater chance of making a typo and introducing a bug.

However, in this case, the fact that the range is always 20 points allows you to use a little math to fit a `switch` block:

```
int k = (input - 1) / 20; 
switch (k) { 
   case 0: 
       System.out.println ("Your grade is F. So sorry.");
   break;
   case 1:
       System.out.println ("Your grade is D");
   break;
   case 2:
       System.out.println ("Your grade is C");
       break;
```

and so on.

If I may, I'd like to offer some suggestions outside the scope of your question.

Instead of having multiple lines that all include "Your grade is ", calculate the grade as a single character or a `String` that contains a single character:

```
int k = (input - 1) / 20; 
char grade;
    switch (k) { 
       case 0: 
           grade = 'F';
       break;
       case 1:
           grade = 'D';
       break;
       case 2:
           grade = 'C';
           break;
```

and so on. It would be followed by

```
System.out.println ("Your grade is " + grade);
```

Here is a way to avoid both `if ... else` chain and `switch` block.

```
char [] grade = {'F','D','C','B','A'};
... 
int k = (input - 1) / 20;
System.out.println ("Your grade is " + grade [k]);
```

This assumes there is something to guard against the possibility that `input` will be less than zero or greater than 100.

Comment: By the way, the lowest range actually has 21 values, not 20.